# JavaScript incorrectly parsing HTML input value

Tags: javascript, java, function, parsing

I am creating a HTML page and I want to make it so that what ever the user types in a text box, it goes in a manually updated URL.

Here is my src..

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>
        Signature Creator
    </title>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <br>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">-->
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="title" name="JacobSignatureCreatorTitle" placeholder="Title" width="10px"><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="subtitle" name="JacobSignatureCreatorSubTitle" placeholder="Subtitle" width="10px"><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="line1" name="JacobSignatureCreatorLineOne" placeholder="Line #1" width="10px"><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="line2" name="JacobSignatureCreatorLineTwo" placeholder="Line #2" width="10px"><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="line3" name="JacobSignatureCreatorLineThree" placeholder="Line #3" width="10px"><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="getVariables()" value="Get 'err done!"><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><center>
        <img id="photo">
    </center>
    <script>
        function getVariables() {
            if (document.getElementById("title").value == null) {
                var title = "";
            } else {
                var title = document.getElementById("title").value.toString;
            }
            if (document.getElementsByName('subtitle').value == null) {
                var subtitle = "";
            } else {
                var subtitle = document.getElementsByName('subtitle').value.toString;
            }
            var line1 = document.getElementsByName('line1').value;
            var line2 = document.getElementsByName('line2').value;
            var line3 = document.getElementsByName('line3').value;
            drawIframe();
        }

        function drawIframe() {
            document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://sig.bensdaman.com/v2/image.png?title=" + title + "&sub=" + subtitle + "&line1=" + line1 + "&line2=" + line2 + "&line3=" + line3;
        }
    </script>
```

All I'm getting back from the URL is this..

```
http://sig.bensdaman.com/v2/image.png?title=[object HTMLInputElement]&sub=[object HTMLInputElement]&line1=[object HTMLInputElement]&line2=[object HTMLInputElement]&line3=[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Comment: `toString` is a method. You should use it like this `toString()`. `toString` is not required here, `document.getElementById("title").value` itself will yield you the value.

Comment: What is the error you got? As for now what i found was you are trying to access local variables declared in `getVariables()` method from `drawIframe()` method.

Comment: @Kesavan I tried this like document.getElementById("title").toString(), and it dosent work.

Comment: @Kesavan Im not getting any errors. Since its returning [object HTMLElementInput] as a string instead of what's in the text box.

Comment: Note that since `document.getElementById("title").value` will either throw an error (where there is no element with that ID and hence an attempt is made to access the *value* property of *null*) or return a string, then `document.getElementById("title").value == null` will always be false, so only the *else* branch will ever be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of the variables, they are local to to the `getVariables()`. In `drawIframe` when you access variables like `title` it is not referring to the variables created in `getVariables()` instead it is referring to the properties of the window object, the `id`s of elements will be accessible as properties of the window object(ie like global variables) so when you say `subtitle` in `drawIframe`, it is referring to the dom element with id `drawIframe` whose `toString()` returns `[object HTMLElementInput]`.

So just pass the variables as parameters to `drawIframe` like

```
function getVariables() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var subtitle = document.getElementById('subtitle').value;
    var line1 = document.getElementsByName('line1').value;
    var line2 = document.getElementsByName('line2').value;
    var line3 = document.getElementsByName('line3').value;
    drawIframe(title, subtitle, line1, line2, line3);
}

function drawIframe(title, subtitle, line1, line2, line3) {
    document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://sig.bensdaman.com/v2/image.png?title=" + title + "&sub=" + subtitle + "&line1=" + line1 + "&line2=" + line2 + "&line3=" + line3;
}
```